# Complexity of an algorithm: why 'about'?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm studying numerical analysis and I can read that an algorithm has a complexity of "about n^2/2".

I know that complexity has something to do with write/read/multiply/sum operations, but I can't understand why 'about' and not 'precisely'.

Comment: What would be the unit?

Comment: If you want to be more precisely use time complexity T(n).

Comment: actually it depends on the level at which you are operating.  when you are analyzing the algorithm, it makes sense to just look at growth rate, so "about" or O(.) is adequate.  however, at the next level where you are implementing the algorithm, it makes sense to count precisely how many operations of each.  even one level down, it becomes useful to even count the # of clock cycles.  it all depends on at what level you are operating, and as it happens, the book/class you are studying operates at an algorithm complexity level.

Answer (score 1):

In algorithmic analysis, it's common to only describe the growth rate of the algorithm via the dominant growth term.  For example, if the algorithm has a real runtime of n<sup>2</sup>/2 + 13n + 1, then as n gets large (say, n > 50), pretty much all of the runtime is explained by the n<sup>2</sup>/2 term and very little is contributed by the other two terms.

In much of computer science, algorithms are described using big-O notation, which completely discards everything except the dominant growth term, and even then discards all constant factors.  In numerical computing, it's typically just to keep the dominant growth term and its constant factor, since for large inputs that term determines almost all of the runtime.  The constant factor is still useful for comparing different algorithms, though.

So in short - people *could* get a precise analysis, but it would not be very useful for large problem sizes.  The dominant growth term is really all that matters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is also interesting is that standard cs analyses (e.g. big O, big theta, etc.) completely ignore constants because of the way the definitions are made.  in reality, the constant makes a big difference!  for example, if your algorithm is O(f(n)) where f(n) is 2 hours, a constant of 10 vs a constant of 1 makes a HUGE difference (namely, 18 hours!).  this is a flaw in the big-O and others.  so in fact, precise analysis **IS** useful.  I suspect that the specifics are omitted for simplicity and also to keep in line with the hierarchy of algorithm growth rate analysis.